# Agora Video SDK user-unpublished event get called for other remote users also

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, agora.io

This is my useEffect code. I have subscribed to the user-joined, user-unpublished events. When multiple remote users join the channel, their video gets published successfully. When any of the remote user leaves the channel, all remote users get unpublished somehow.

```
useEffect(() => {
        let initClientCallbacks = () => {
            videoCallContext.client.on("user-published", async (remoteUser, mediaType) => {
                await videoCallContext.client.subscribe(remoteUser, mediaType);
                if (mediaType == "video") {
                    console.log("subscribe video success");
                    // remoteUser.videoTrack.play(document.getElementById("subscriber"));
                    setUsers((prevUsers) => {
                        return [...prevUsers, remoteUser];
                    });
                }
                if (mediaType == "audio") {
                    console.log("subscribe audio success");
                    remoteUser.audioTrack.play();
                }
                const p = document.getElementById('publisher');
                p.style.width = '30%';
                p.style.height = '30%';
                p.style.left = '10px';
                p.style.bottom = '10px';
            })





            videoCallContext.client.on("user-unpublished", async (user, type) => {
                if (user.uid === leavingUserUidRef.current) {
                    return;
                }

                console.log("unpublished", user, type);

                if (type === "audio") {
                    user.audioTrack?.stop();
                }

                if (type === "video") {
                    setUsers((prevUsers) => {
                        return prevUsers.filter((User) => User.uid !== user.uid);
                    });
                }

                setInitiatePolling(true);
            });

            videoCallContext.client.on("user-left", (user) => {
                console.log("leaving", user);
                console.log("leaving id", user.uid);
                leavingUserUidRef.current = user.uid;
                setUsers((prevUsers) => {
                    return prevUsers.filter((User) => User.uid !== user.uid);
                });
                setInitiatePolling(true);
            });


        }

        initClientCallbacks();

   
    }, [appointmentInformation?.id]);
```

I have tried to store leaving user id to make sure only that gets unpublished. But somehow, other remote users also get unpublished.